# Call to undefined method getPosition() - Why and Fix

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I made an extbase extension with a class `Appointment` with a property `expertises` und another one `subExpertises` of the same type.
This is how they look like in the `Appointment` class (`subExpertises` is the same):

```
    /**
     * expertises
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<...\Domain\Model\Expertise>
     */
    protected $expertises = NULL;

    /**
     * Adds an expertise
     *
     * @param ...\Domain\Model\Expertise $expertise
     * @return void
     */
    public function addExpertise(...\Domain\Model\Expertise $expertise) {
        $this->expertises->attach($expertise);
    }
```

I get an error when executing this code in my controller after editing the appointment in a fluid form:

```
/**
 *
 * @param \Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment
 * @return void
 */
public function bookAction(\Domain\Model\Appointment $appointment) {

    //empty all expertises of appointment - then fill them with the selected from lawyer
    $appointment->setExpertises(new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage());
    $appointment->setSubExpertises(new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage());

    //add all checked expertises of lawyer to appointment
    foreach ($appointment->getLawyer()->getExpertises() as $expertise) {
        if ($expertise->getChecked()) {
            $appointment->addExpertise($expertise);
        }
        foreach ($expertise->getSubExpertises() as $subExpertise) {
            if ($subExpertise->getChecked()) {
                $appointment->addSubExpertise($subExpertise);
            }
        }
    }
    $this->appointmentRepository->update($appointment);
}
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method \Domain\Model\Expertise::getPosition() in /var/www/typo3_src/typo3_src-6.2.25/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php on line 453

Now it seems that TYPO3 thinks `Expertise` is of type `ObjectStorage` because it tries to call `getPosition()` but I have no clue **why** it does that and **what I should change** in order to successfully save my `Appointment` object with the new `Expertises`.

I tried debugging the appointment object, but I couldn't find the problem - it seems okay to me, it just shows that `expertises` und `subExpertises` have been modified.

Comment: ... you have different spellings of expertise, singluar in the property, plural in the method.

Comment: I checked my text again, but it was fine - the props are objectStorage so plural `expertises` and `subExpertises` the class name is `Expertise` and `addExpertise` only adds one, so it should be singular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getter methods in Extbase aren't magic, you have to explicitly define them.

If you're dealing with a n:n-relation, you also need to initialize the Property as ObjectStorage in your model and configure it in the TCA.

```
/**
 * Initialize all ObjectStorage properties.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->yourProperty = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track - after noticing that `subExpertise` wasn't initialized as object storage - I traced back the reason: It was because I set the relation in my extension builder to `1:n` instead of `m:n`